# React js Role based authorization

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, authorization

I have implemented **role based authorization** for each API from app.js in my **react app**. I have
declare and initialize **list of roles inside config.js**. I already have current user role(**Dynamic data fetch from database**) inside CONTEXT API.So for every API hit, I will authorize user role by comparing LoggedIn user role with static roleList (implemented inside config.js)  whether it includes in the list or not. If not, will redirect them to unauthorized screen. else will navigate them to respective screen from my private route. **All working fine, my doubt is whether this is the standard way or not. Or else is their any other efficient ways to make it work.**

App.js api sample :

```
    <PrivateRoute allowedRoles={Config.ROLESLIST}
        exact
        path="/operation"
        component={OperationPageManager}
   />
```

Private route :

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component,allowedRoles, ...rest }) {
    const MsalAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
    const authUser = usePrivate();
    const { authKey, projects, isAuthenticated,accountType } = authUser.user;
    const [data, setData] = useState({ authKey: null, projects: [], isAuthenticated: MsalAuthenticated });
    const [canAccessUI,setAccess] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isAuthenticated && authKey !== null && accountType) {
            if(allowedRoles instanceof Array && allowedRoles.length > 0) {
                allowedRoles.includes(accountType) ? setAccess(1) : setAccess(2);
            }
            setData({ authKey: authKey, projects: projects, isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated });
        }
    }, [isAuthenticated, authKey, projects, MsalAuthenticated, accountType]);
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
            (data.isAuthenticated && data.authKey === null && canAccessUI === 0 ? <Spinner /> :  
            (data.isAuthenticated && data.authKey !== null && canAccessUI === 1) ? (<Component {...props} />) : 
            (data.isAuthenticated && data.authKey !== null && canAccessUI === 2) ? <Unauthorized description="Access denied,You are not an authorized user to access this page"/> : 
            (<Login />))}
        />
    );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Config.js :

```
export default {
  ROLESLIST : ["super_admin","admin","management","operator"]
};
```